# Newtonian motion from a simplified Schwarzschild's metric in 1+1D

Tags: newtonian-gravity, metric-tensor, geodesics

I've read that the simplified Schwarzschild's metric in the $t$-$z$ space

$$ds^2=\left(1+2\phi\right)dt^2-dz^2$$

could (approximately) reproduce the classical motion of a particle in a constant gravitational field (say near the earth's surface). So we can use the classical weight force potential $\phi=gh=gz$ and the metric becomes

$$ ds^2=\left(1+2gz\right)dt^2-dz^2.\tag{1}$$

I'd like to check that this metric actually leads to a geodesic that, with proper initial conditions, has the classic Newtonian form

$$z=z_0-g t^2$$

Working with the Christoffel symbols using the metric $(1)$ with indexes $\;\{1,2\}\;$ representing the variables $\;\{t, z\}\;$ I got

$\Gamma^1_{12}=\Gamma^1_{21}=\frac{g}{1+2gz}$

$\Gamma^2_{11}=g$

and the geodesic equations become

$\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{2g}{1+2gz}\frac{dt}{d\lambda}\frac{dz}{d\lambda}=0$

$\frac{d^2z}{d\lambda^2}+g\left(\frac{dt}{d\lambda}\right)^2=0\;\;$ (previous error corrected)

The second equation seem promising but I can't make sense of the first one, nor get a solution of this system of ODE.

I think that the problem could be connected with the fact that the geodesic equations use an affine parameter ($\lambda$) whilst the $t$ in Newton's free fall motion in not an affine parameter (?).

Is it possible to get classical motion of a particle from these geodesic equations?

Comment: Your metric look like Rindler metric ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates

Comment: I'm familiar with the approximately Newtonian metric $ds^2 = (1+2\phi)dt^2 - (1-2\phi)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$, but that differs from yours in the spatial part prefactor.  I believe there's a whole chapter devoted to it in Schutz's GR text.

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be an error in your spatial geodesic equation.  This should be a statement of Newton's second law, something like $m\ddot{x} = F = -m\nabla\phi$, where $\phi$ is the gravitational potential.  For a uniform gravitational field this should be $\ddot{x} = -g$.

(I find that numerical super- and sub-scripts can get confusing, so I'm going to just use the coordinate letters.  I'm also going to use dots to refer to affine derivatives)

### spatial geodesic equation

If we write out all of the terms of the sum we get:
\begin{align}
\ddot{z} + {\Gamma^z}_{\alpha\beta} \dot{x}^\alpha\dot{x}^\beta &= 0 \\
\ddot{z} + {\Gamma^z}_{tt} \dot{t}\dot{t} + {\Gamma^z}_{zz} \dot{z}\dot{z} + 2 {\Gamma^z}_{tz} \dot{t}\dot{z} &= 0
\end{align}
In the question you state that only ${\Gamma^z}_{tt}$ is non-vanishing.  This leaves
$$\ddot{z} + {\Gamma^z}_{tt} \dot{t}\dot{t} = 0$$

(this differs from your spatial geodesic which has $\dot{z}$'s instead of $\dot{t}$'s)

The Christoffel symbol depends on derivatives of the metric.  For your metric this reduces to
$$ {\Gamma^z}_{tt} = -\frac{g^{zz}}{2}\,g_{tt,z} = +\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dz}(1+2\phi) = \frac{d}{dz}\phi.$$
There's our $\nabla\phi$!

If we use proper time as the affine parameter, then $\dot{t}=\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\gamma$, the Lorentz factor. If the particle is moving slowly, then $\gamma\approx 1$.

We can rewrite the spatial geodesic equation as:

$$\ddot{z} \approx -\frac{d}{dz}\phi = -g. $$

### An alternate metric

If you used the approximate Newtonian metric I suggested in a comment
$$ds^2 = (1+2\phi)dt^2 - (1-2\phi)dz^2, $$
you'd find that the ${\Gamma^z}_{zz}$ Christoffel no longer vanishes.  But by the same slow speed approximation as used above $\dot{t}^2 \gg \dot{z}^2$, so you can safely neglect that term.

### temporal geodesic equation

The temporal geodesic equation should be a statement about the energy of the system.  This is easiest to see by putting the equation in terms of momentum.  Multiplying the temporal geodesic by the particle mass, $m$:
$$m\ddot{t} + 2m{\Gamma^t}_{tz}\dot{t}\dot{z} = 0$$

$$p^t = m \dot{t} = E \implies m\ddot{t} = \dot{E}$$

If energy is conserved, then $\dot{E} = 0$ at least to our first order approximation.  The second term better vanish:

$$\dot{E} + 2m\frac{g}{1+2gz}\dot{t}\dot{z} = 0,$$

but I'm not sure how. We could say $\dot{z}\approx 0$, which doesn't seem fair.

The way I'm currently wrapping my head around it is by going back to sum of Christoffels:
$$\ddot{t} + {\Gamma^t}_{tt} \dot{t}\dot{t} + {\Gamma^t}_{zz} \dot{z}\dot{z} + 2 {\Gamma^t}_{tz} \dot{t}\dot{z} = 0.$$

The ${\Gamma^t}_{tt} \dot{t}\dot{t}$ should dominate in the slow speed approximation.  We could decide to approximate the other terms to zero at this point.  The remaining ${\Gamma^t}_{tt}$ depends on a time derivative of the metric which leads to a term $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$.

With this logic we can say
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=0 \implies \dot{E}=0.$$
This says energy is conserved in a static gravitational potential, which is true of Newtonian gravity.

Comment: I think it is (at the end) ...by going back to sum of Christoffels:
$\ddot{t}+\Gamma^t_{tt}\dot{t}\dot{t}+\Gamma^t_{zz}\dot{z}\dot{z}+2\Gamma^t_{tz}\dot{t}\dot{z}=0$

Comment: @LucaM, good catch!